# Sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{\sin (n)}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I have this problem and I need some help on it.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{\sin (n)}{n^2}$$

So for this, I know that the sin value will always be between -1 < n < 1.

And the series only converges if the limit is equal to 0, otherwise, it diverges by Divergence Test.

The problem is that I am having trouble taking the limit of the function:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2}$$

So if anyone has any suggestions on how I may accomplish this, that would be great.

Comment: Actually, you don't have $-1 < n <1$ but rather $-1 \le \sin n \le 1.$

Comment: Ah, I see thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Guide:

- Note that

$$\left|\frac{\sin n}{n^2}\right| \le \frac1{n^2}$$

Comment: So would I take the limit of $$\frac{1}{n^2}$$ which is 0. So then the sequence converges -- this is squeeze theorem right?

Comment: yup, after you show that the absolute value of $|a_n|$ converges to $0$, you can conclude that $a_n$ converges to $0$ as well. Alternatively, view it as $-\frac1{n^2} \le \frac{\sin n}{n^2} \le \frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We need to observe that $$\frac{-1}{n^2} \leq \frac{(-1)^n\sin(n)}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-1}{n^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = 0$, it follows by the squeeze theorem that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n\sin(n)}{n^2} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

If you know that for some positive $M$, $-M\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x$, then $-M\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)\leq M$.

Now use the fact that $-1 \leq (-1)^n\sin(n)\leq 1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac 1 {n^2}=0$ to conclude that the answer to your question is zero.